# Android своя клавиатура в альбомной ориентации сдвигает экран, как исправить

Tags: android

При долгом нажатии на выделенный текст ограничители-курсоры всплывают в нежелательном месте. В чем может быть проблема?

[image: скрин]

Добавлю разметку

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_uname"
        android:layout_width="775dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/box_shadow"
        android:ems="23"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:paddingLeft="6dp"
        android:textColor="@color/label"
        android:textSize="23sp"
        android:cursorVisible="true"
        android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
        android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
        >
```

Выяснила интересный факт - на андроиде 4.2.2 планшета Ирбис реагирует, как описано выше. Тестирую на своих ЛыЖах (5.0.2) ту же кастомную клавиатуру - все пучком, реагирует адекватно.Теперь я в тупике :(

UPD: выяснила, что этот баг появляется в ландшафтной ориентации. В портретной все как надо - выплывает копи паст бар, выделение никуда не смещается.

UPD: вывод: моя клавиатура сдвигает в альбомной ориентации эту панельку, получается, некорректно видит размеры экрана. Какие мысли на этот счет?

Comment: А с другой клавиатурой такой же эффект?

Comment: неа, с родной клавиатурой другой хаос - после выделения и лонг преса, когда сверху вываливается панелька копипаст, выделенное слово под пальцем смещается на ширину этой панельки, и если там есть поле, копируется туда. Ужас.

Comment: Так а код разметки скиньте

Comment: Попробуйте http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6275299/how-to-disable-copy-paste-from-to-edittext . По описанию, возможно, это то, что вам надо.

Comment: Спасибо за наводку! Тот вопрос не очень подходит, но я все равно попробовала, безуспешно, зато выяснила важную вещь - если с данной клавиатурой тыкать в EditText в портретном режиме - то панелька копи-паст появляется, и выделение реагирует адекватно - никуда не смещается!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Итак. Проблема в полноэкранном режиме клавиатуры, который стоит по умолчанию в альбомной ориентации. В классе `extends InpetMethodService` переписала метод

```
 @Override
public boolean onEvaluateFullscreenMode() {
    DisplayMetrics dm = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    float displayHeight = dm.heightPixels;
    // If the display is more than X inches high, don't go to fullscreen
    // mode
    float dimen = getResources().getDimension(
            R.dimen.max_height_for_fullscreen);
    if (displayHeight > dimen) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return super.onEvaluateFullscreenMode();
    }
}
```

В `@Override onStartInputView()` на всякий случай вызвала `updateFullscreenMode();` При таком раскладе на планшете свои клавиатура работает аналогично стандартной - является панель копирования-вставки, адекватно выделяется слово, без сдвигов, как на скрине.